# C# Loading Screen While Components Load

Tags: c#, screen, loading

I want to make a screen that is displaying the message Login in a label while all the components are loading in a form.When i execute the game it stays in blank screen for about 5 seconds before showing all the design so i want it to load until it is fully loaded.

Comment: You might want to mention what technology stack you're using.  In addition, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I haven't tried anything because i dunno how :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a new "splash screen" form that you hide when loading is complete. Don't display your current form until loading is complete.

This is one way to do it:

1. Initialize and show the splash window
2. Initialize but keep the main window hidden
3. When main window is fully loaded, show it and close the splash window

There is a lot of sample code out there, just google for it. Some links:

http://crazorsharp.blogspot.se/2009/06/creating-splash-screen-in-net-with.html
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5454/A-Pretty-Good-Splash-Screen-in-C
http://www.codersource.net/MicrosoftNet/CWinForms/CreatingaSplashScreeninC.aspx

Comment: Well..i didn't fully understand...can you show me with a code please?

Comment: I don't have any code to show, but I updated my answer with some links.

Comment: But how do I run two forms at once without threading? And once I am running the splash on a separate thread, I can't stop it from main thread. It will give me object reference not set to an instance of object error.